# Unable to find and click the button

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

> trying to find and click the image with C#. Getting error as below.
>
> new_eog.myclass.Logintest:
>   OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException : Unable to locate element: 
>   "method":"xpath","selector":"//img[contains(@src,'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/b
>   tn/btn_donate_LG.gif')]"}
>
> Below is the html code for the image.

```
<input type="image" border="0" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_donate_LG.gif" name="submit">
```

> Below is the code i am using to locate and click the image link.

```
 IWebElement temp = wd.FindElement(By.XPath("//img[contains(@src,'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_donate_LG.gif')]"));
 temp.Click();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an input tag, so it should be

```
By.XPath("//input[contains(@src,'www.sandbox.paypal.com')]")
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the below statement:

wd.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@src='https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_donate_LG.gif']")).click();

Answer (score 0):

You can use By.Name instead of XPath, which i suspect would be slow in performance wise. So you can try out below code

```
IWebElement temp = wd.FindElement(By.Name("submit"));
temp.Click();
```